# Exception: Failed to parse class ID from URL

Tags: python

I'm subscribed to skillshare but turns out skillshare's UI is a huge mess and unproductive for learning. So, I am seeking for a way to mass download course(single course) at once.

I found this github.

https://github.com/crazygroot/skillsharedownloader

And it has a google collab link as well at the bottom.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hUUPDDql0QLul7lB8NQNaEEq-bbayEdE#scrollTo=xunEYHutBEv%2F

I'm getting the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Skillsharedownloader/ss.py", line 11, in <module>
    dl.download_course_by_url(course_url)
  File "/root/Skillsharedownloader/downloader.py", line 34, in download_course_by_url
    raise Exception('Failed to parse class ID from URL')
Exception: Failed to parse class ID from URL
```

This is the course link that I'm using:

https://www.skillshare.com/en/classes/React-JS-Learn-by-examples/1186943986/

Comment: And, what does that line, #34 of "download_course_by_url", say? Remember to show enough of the problem that your voluntary friends on Stack Overflow might be able to see the problem without clicking on links. The more effort you put in, the more likely to get a helpful answer.

Comment: Also, I'm sure this is against their terms and conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar issue. The problem was that it requires the URL to look like `https://www.skillshare.com/classes/.*?/(\d+)`.

If your copying the URL from the address bar, check the URL again and make sure it has the same format. The current one looks like `https://www.skillshare.com/en/classes/xxxxx`. So simply remove `/en`.

Comment: should I change phpssid? or keep it same?